# Converting MATLAB Slicing into Python using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, scipy

I am having trouble converting some MATLAB code into python.  I am trying to build a signal by adding in shifted copies of base signal into a much longer one.  The code that works in MATLAB is

```
function [time, signal] = generateRandomSignal(pulse,data,samples,Tb)
N = length(data);
time = linspace(0,N*Tb,samples*N);
signal = zeros(1,length(time));
k = 1;
for n = 1:N
        window = k:k+samples-1;
        signal(window) = signal(window) + data(n)*pulse;
        k = k + samples;
end
```

In python using the variable to slice the larger array wasn't working so I changed that but now I got what I think should work but I keep getting errors about inconsistent array sizes even though when I inspect the sizes in a debugger it looks like it should work.

```
from numpy import *
def generateRandomSignal(pulse,data,samples,Tb):
    N = data.size;
    time = linspace(0,N*Tb,samples*N);
    signal = zeros((1,time.size));
    k = 0;
    for n in range(0,N):
            signal[k:k+samples] = signal[k:k+samples].copy() + data[n]*pulse[:].copy();
            k = k + samples;
    return time, signal
```

What is the correct way to do this in Python?

EDIT: Minimal expected input and output

```
Input
  data = [1, -1, 0, 1, 1]
  pulse = [1, 1, 1]
  samples = 3. #length of pulse
  Tb = 0.1

Output
  signal = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
  time = vector of 15 points evenly spaced from 0 to 0.3.  (Not the problem)
```

EDIT2 Error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1920,) (1,4410)
```

That is the actual error produced.  (1,4410) is the correct shape for the pulse array but I have no idea where the 1920 is coming from or what the empty comma means

Comment: Can you put a minimalistic example input and expected output?

Comment: Added a small sample input and output to hopefully explain my intention better

Comment: The parameter samples can be avoided? (As `samples = len(pulse)`

Comment: Only in the minimal example which is why it isn't avoided in general

Comment: A bit confused with the addition part of the question.  `pulse` has 4410 elements, but the number of samples is 1920.  I'm not sure how MATLAB wasn't throwing an error because the way the two vectors are being added are inconsistent in dimensions... unless I'm not reading the code properly.

Comment: Use `.shape` rather than `.size`.  Shape has information about each dimension, size is just the total number of items.

Comment: @rayryeng I still think that the code can't work for `samples != len(pulse)`... Unless I'm not reading it properly neither..

Comment: @imaluengo I agree that the code as posted only works if samples = len(pulse).  Both were used in the case where the pulse is not rectangular and the window and pulse need to be wider than 1 bit time to account for inter-symbol interference.  It could probably be reduced to one parameter but I believe I originally had both to make the time calculation easier. Nonetheless I was able to get it working after it was pointed out that a length n vector is not the same as a [1,n] array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your definition of `signal` to `signal = zeros(time.size)`. Unlike Matlab, NumPy's 1D arrays have shape `(N,)`, not `(N,1)`.

Comment: After looking into the shapes of all my variables i found data was a (1,1920) and doing data[n] gave an array for all 1920 entries not each item one by one.  After changing it to data[0,n] the code works as expected. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why you should have 0 index in signal:

> signal[0,k:k+samples] = signal[0,k:k+samples].copy() + data[n]*pulse[:].copy();

Comment: That was left over from a test when I was trying to force the dimensions to match.  However, removing it doesn't make a difference